# Google Play Games : Auth Error

Tags: android, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I installed the google play games services on my Unity3D game, and only some functions work.

Indeed, authentication goes well:

```
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 8/1/16 3:14:08 p.m. +02: 00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: sign_in status: VALID
```

and

```
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 1/8/16 3:14:08 p.m. +02: 00 DEBUG: Found User: [Player: 'XXX' (id gXXXXXXXXXXXX)]
```

In addition, the `Social.localUser.id` function works. Unfortunately, `Social.localUser.authenticated` returns False and I can not log off via `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut();` :

```
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 8/1/16 3:14:36 p.m. +02: 00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_OUT status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem which seems odd and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [related issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/225) which recommends to add your testing gmail ids on Google Play Developer Console.

> Go to Google Play Developer Console -> Game Services -> Testing and add your testing gmail ids.

These error happens when you don't add a tester to the tester's list in the Game Services section of the Play Dev console.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've already make that : [see here](http://originalsbytoto.com/img/laserman/error.png) (here it's the French Console because I'm French :) ) Else, can I publish Game Services without publish my game now ?